# Swift uiview shadow only works on iphone5

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a shadow under my uivew. It works on a Iphone 5 but the shadow only gets applied 2/3 of the views lenght when trying on a iphone 6 plus.

code:

```
myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        myView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        myView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myView.frame.width, height: myView.frame.height)).CGPath
```

The constraints of the view is:

**Height: 41**

**Leading to superview: 0**

**Trailing to superview: 0**

Comment: Any chance you're generating the shadow path prior to layout?

Comment: @Tommy I don't think so,  I am running this in viewDidLoad()

Comment: At `viewDidLoad` constraints won't yet have been applied; you probably need to update your `shadowPath` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. If I weren't typing this out via phone I'd check and possibly promote this to an answer.

Comment: Where are your `Y` constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You're applying your shadow before layout has completed as @Tommy mentioned in the comments.

Move your code from your `viewDidLoad` to your `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        myView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        myView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myView.frame.width, height: myView.frame.height)).CGPath
    }
```

Also, have you set a `Y` constraint on your view? I'd imagine you'd want to `pin` it to the top of your `Superview`.